# How do I change a display using TreeView?

Tags: c#

I'm trying to change a panel to a specific form (as this is the only way I can fathom it) based on the selected TreeView node. For example, in Visual Studio, if you right-click on "Solution 'solutionname' (1 Project)", click 'Properties', it comes up with a tree list on the left side. When you click on a selection, the right pane changes.

I've searched continuously for hours the previous few days and only found a tutorial showing how it can affect a webBrowser control.

This is a farfetched example that I can understand:

`private void tree_NodeMouseClick(object sender, TreeNodeMouseClickEventArgs e)

{

treeNode nName      = e.Node;

            //For testing:

            string pg           = "";

            pg = nName.Tag;

            if (pg == "Form2") display = Form2;

    }`

Display is a panel. I know this is absolutely wrong, but I couldn't find any proper method using my search terms.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to set `Visible` on all your panels to `false`, except for the one you want to display which will be set to `true`.

WinForms does not have any particularly nice way of setting this up. You could set the `Tag` property of each node to be a reference to the panel (this has to be done programmatically - the designer won't let you do it), then iterate through the entire tree view to set `((Panel)node.Tag).Visible = false` followed by `((Panel)e.Node.Tag).Visible = true` or you can maintain the list separately. If you don't have many panels, a switch/if-else block may be okay, too.

Comment: So in designer, I would have to create panels upon panels? That seems pretty hectic, yet this seems to be a generic and commonly used method to create menus. I'd like to think that there is a more efficient, cleaner method of doing this.

Take uTorrent for example; clicking Options -> Preferences (or CTRL + P), you can see the list view; upon selecting a node, the right pane alters flawlessly. Were those designed panels upon panels?

Comment: I would assume so. Changing the visibility of an entire panel is far preferable to dynamically creating/destroying UI elements. Using a panel is grouping windows (child windows = controls) within another window and making them inherit visibility (and other properties).